# Redux state mutation despite making state copy with spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, deep-copy

Why I getting a state mutation alert when I'm making a copy of object with spread operator ?
I'm trying to make a shop cart with redux. When adding an element or decrese its quantity I dispatch an action that update de state.
In my reducer if product is not added yet, I return a new copy of state array with the new object. If it is already added, I iterate with map (that returns a new array) and with a copy of product that I'm increasing and its `qty` property increased.
**The problem is with this property What is the correct way to update this property without mutating the state?**

reducer

```
case types.ADD_TO_CART_SUCCESS:
  const isAdded = state.cart.find(item => item.sku === action.product.sku);
  if (!isAdded) action.product.qty = 1;
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: !isAdded
      ? [action.product, ...state.cart]
      : state.cart.map(item =>
          item.sku === action.product.sku
            ? { ...item, qty: ++item.qty }
            : item
        ),
  };
```

Violation warning

```
Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `user.cart.0.qty`. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action {"type":"ADD_TO_CART_SUCCESS"....}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *are* mutating the current item. Pre/post incremementing/decrementing will mutate the current object reference it operates on.

```
case types.ADD_TO_CART_SUCCESS:
  const isAdded = state.cart.find(item => item.sku === action.product.sku);
  if (!isAdded) action.product.qty = 1;
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: !isAdded
      ? [action.product, ...state.cart]
      : state.cart.map(item =>
          item.sku === action.product.sku
            ? { ...item, qty: ++item.qty } // <-- This mutates the current item.qty
            : item
        ),
  };
```

You can however return an incremented value, current `item.qty + 1`

```
case types.ADD_TO_CART_SUCCESS:
  const isAdded = state.cart.find(item => item.sku === action.product.sku);
  if (!isAdded) action.product.qty = 1;
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: !isAdded
      ? [action.product, ...state.cart]
      : state.cart.map(item =>
          item.sku === action.product.sku
            ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 }
            : item
        ),
  };
```

I suspect your code functions as expected, since you *do* correctly replace the entire cart array and the item you mutate is the item you want to update anyway, but this is indicative that your reducer may not a pure function, i.e. the previous state should still equal the previous state in all aspects *after* the reducer computes the next state.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which will warn about accidental state mutations by default.  That's great, because it clearly caught a mutation in this case.

But, what's even better is that [Redux Toolkit uses Immer inside to let you write "mutating" state updates in reducers!](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#simplifying-reducers-with-createreducer).  That means that your reducer logic can be simplified down to this:

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCartSuccess(state, action) {
      const item = state.cart.find(item => item.sku === action.payload.product.sku);
      if (item) {
        item.qty++;
      } else {
        action.product.qty = 1;
        state.cart.unshift(action.payload.product);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this a couple of times, try this code:

```
const addItemToCart = (cartItems, cartItemToAdd) => {
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
    (cartItem) => cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
  );

  if (existingCartItem) {
    return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
      cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
        ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
        : cartItem
    );
  }

  return [...cartItems, { ...cartItemToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
};
```